# How do I fix multiple python environments on jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter, conda

I just opened up jupyter and when I create a new notebook, it shows two notebooks

- Python[default]
- Python[conda root]

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Which issue exactly?

Comment: well normally, it should just show Python[3.5] or whatever version you running. I don't want to encounter issues in the future when sharing notebooks or for any other reasons.

Comment: By default it shows `python3` or `python2`. Anaconda devs decided to remove those and instead show a kernel for each environment. The package `nb_conda_kernels` is responsible for that behavior. You can uninstall it (and also disable the jupyter extension) to go back to the previous behavior. The new kernel names are not really a problem when sharing your notebooks. Jupyter will tell you that the kernel does not exist and asks you to switch to different one.